# Sceen goes blank when using browser for certain tasks using 16.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I am using

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

on a gigabyte brix S which comes with a built in intel card
lshw -C video 
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0

I am using a HDMI to DVI converter

Symptoms:
I can reliably cause the issue by opening google chrome, then navigate to gmail, as soon as I click on a check-box (to select a mail item) the screen goes blank and does not recover, unless a navigate to the different tab in the browser (ctrl+tab).

In firefox the precise same problem does not occur, however the screen regularly goes blank when browsing other sites in firefox. usually scrolling the mouse will fix it.  Also  If I try to watch any youtube video, the screen flickers off and on ( mostly off).

Things I've tried: (based on existing askubuntu posts)

I've removed the "hardware acceleration" setting in chromne

Checked for latest driver 
apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel

even this 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa

rebooted

the problem still persists

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

problem was the monitor and or the HDMI to dvi converter.
I replaced monitor with one that supports HDMI and re-installed 16.04.
 display & driver working properly